FastAPI middleware masks exceptions in background tasks -- why?
Consider the following minimal example. This is a FastAPI handler that enqueues a background task. This task will throw.
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI, Request, Response, status

app = FastAPI(title="Debug demo", description="", version="0.1.0")

@app.middleware("http")
async def noop_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    return await call_next(request)

@app.post("/test")
async def test(req: Request, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks) -> Response:
    def _fail():
        raise ValueError("TEST")

    background_tasks.add_task(_fail)

    return Response(content="", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)

The app is run via uvicorn (uvicorn my_demo:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000).
If the no-op middleware is commented out, the exception thrown by the task will appear in uvicorn logs:
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last): <...>

This is the desired/expected behavior. However, with the middleware in place, the exceptions will be silently swallowed (not logged). Obviously one can work around this by making sure every background task catches and logs its errors, but the default behavior is surprising. What is going on and how can one avoid middleware from interfering with exception logging?

Does this answer your question? You might also find this answer helpful.

I checked this code on previous versions, it works as you expect up to FastAPI 0.108.0 (not include 0.108.0).

It's not a solution, but downgrading Starlette to 0.28.0 makes it working (fastapi            0.108.0 + Starlette 0.28.0)

I thinks it's better to ask this question on GitHub. It looks like a bug

I think it's a bug of Starlette.
I created a simple example code that works as you expect on Starlette 0.28.0, but doesn't log exception on Starlette 0.29.0.
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware
from starlette.routing import Route
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse

class CustomHeaderMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(self, request, call_next):
        response = await call_next(request)
        return response

async def bg_task():
    raise ValueError("TEST")

def homepage(request):
    task = BackgroundTask(bg_task)
    message = {'status': 'Ok'}
    return JSONResponse(message, background=task)

routes = [
    Route('/', homepage),
]

middleware = [
    Middleware(CustomHeaderMiddleware)
]

app = Starlette(routes=routes, middleware=middleware)

I think you should ask this question on https://github.com/encode/starlette.
UPD: There is already an issue there (https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/2625)
